# InetAddress.getLocalHost() failing on machine running embedded Java

Tags: java, linux, networking

In this post [java H2 hanging on getLocalhost on arm32 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055355/java-hibernate-hanging-on-getlocalhost-on-arm32-device) I had a problem creating database using Hibernate. I have now managed to remove track down the issue to core java with this test program, InetAddress lookup using getByName("localhost") works, but getLocalHost() fails !

Points towards configuration issue with linux machine. localhost is in /etc/hosts

But I am no Linux expert, what could cause this ?

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Addresses
{
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
           InetAddress address= InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
           System.out.println(address.getHostName()+ "-"+address.getHostAddress());

           address= InetAddress.getLocalHost();
           System.out.println(address.getHostName()+ "-"+address.getHostAddress());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Gives

```
localhost-127.0.0.1
java.net.UnknownHostException: N1-ZS10: N1-ZS10: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
        at Addresses.main(Addresses.java:12)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: N1-ZS10: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: I'm confused by the "N1-ZS10" - is that your hostname?  If so, is it defined in /etc/hosts?

Comment: @st=tdubar Yes it is, but I cant add it because /etc/hosts is a read only filesystem (linux on an embedded system), but shoudln't localhost work anyway since localhost is in /etc/hosts or is there anything I can configure on the java side of things suince I cant edit etc/hosts

Comment: It occurred on another system as well and adding the hostname to /etc/hosts did fix the issue but I dont think this should be neccessary